# Open sessions, restore graphical tabs (gvim, windows)

Tags: session, vim

I use gvim and work in tabs. For example, I have 3 tabs open when I `:mksession`. When I later source it, the files will "open" in buffers, as they are visible in the buffers menu, but it doesn't recreate the tabs.

Looking at the example session.vim, it runs `badd` for every file, but I can't see anything that creates new tabs. I tried putting `au BufAdd * tabnew` in my vimrc, but it didn't work as expected.

[My .vimrc](https://gist.github.com/787051)
[Example session.vim](https://gist.github.com/787078)

`sessionoptions="blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,resize,tabpages,winsize"`

Comment: To rule out your .vimrc, you could simply move the file away and see if you can reproduce the behaviour. If it works then, try placing it back with most of it commented out until you can reproduce it again. I can't see anything obvious, although I thought at first the BufEnter hook might be at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the exact right combination of Google search terms will get it for you...

`:au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball`

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage

**edit:** This au command causes Netrw to open a new tab for each directory you browse. A workaround is to run `:tab sball` after opening a session.

Comment: Vim should restore tabs out of the box when you source the session file. Weird!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought! It loads the buffers, but only provides one window (if that's the right terminology).

Answer (score 0):

[ When you open session ]

And make your session save command that `:mks!` next time when You can open session with following.

save session:
`1) :mks!`

Next open session:
`2) vim -S Session.vim`

It's so uesful. Enjoy your code in vim.
Thanks.